# Workaround against initialization variables after F5 key pushed?

Tags: angularjs

I developed the authorization in my web application using angular JS. and after the authorization, I saved the values to the value of angular service, "authService".

But if I pushed F5 function key, the values is gone and return default value. So, Even if I loggin and push f5, I have to log in again.

How can I solve this? If you want related codes, I will attach on this. Thanks.

Comment: please read this, instead of my previous comment! https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

Comment: Ok.  I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, use session cookies and store session information on the server side, fetching that on loading the page. Without doing that, you cannot overcome the issue, as Angular naturally gets re-initialized on every reload.

Comment: Well, you have to somehow match the browser's state with the active session, so if your current server-side code does not support that, then you definitely have to implement it.